# Laço para leitura de arquivo de texto lê a última linha duas vezes

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um teste para leitura de um arquivo txt simples com três números:

1

2

3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {   
  int conta;
  FILE* arq = fopen("dicionario.txt", "r");

  if(arq!=NULL){
    while(!feof(arq)){
      fscanf(arq, "%d", &conta);
      printf("%d\n", conta);
    }
  }

  fclose(arq); 
  return 0;
}
```

Gostaria de saber porque o programa imprime a última linha duas vezes e como resolveria isso.

Comment: com essa alteração no laço funciona normalmente:char c  while((c = getc(arq) ) != EOF). Mas ainda não entendo o pq do primeiro imprimir duas vezes a última linha :/

Comment: Caio, evite de usar a tag c++ em perguntas sobre C. As duas linguagens são bastante diferentes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema está no teste do `while`:

```
while(!feof(arq)){
```

Que na verdade testa se foi feita alguma leitura para além do fim, como a [documentação indica](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/)

> This indicator is generally set by a previous operation on the stream that attempted to read at or past the end-of-file.
>
> Notice that stream's internal position indicator may point to the end-of-file for the next operation, but still, the end-of-file indicator may not be set until an operation attempts to read at that point.

Traduzindo

> Este indicador é ativado por uma operação previa na stream que tentou ler para alem do fim de arquivo.
>
> Note que a posição interna da stream pode estar a apontar para o fim do arquivo para a próxima operação, mas ainda assim, o indicador de fim de arquivo não será ativado até que uma leitura seja feita.

Isto faz com que a ultima leitura leia o `3` que deixa o arquivo no fim, mas depois volta a tentar ler e somente nessa altura ativa o indicador de fim de arquivo, mostrando então duas vezes o `3`.

Para corrigir troque o seu `while` para:

```
while(fscanf(arq, "%d", &conta) == 1) {
    printf("%d\n", conta);
}
```

Assim verifica pelo retorno do [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) se conseguiu ler um número e apenas nesse caso faz a impressão na tela.

Comment: Entendi! Deu certo, obrigado!